# Hypothetical question involving cdf A problm I am doing has $P(X<x)>0$

Tags: probability

If $P(X>x)=1-P(X<x)$, then $P(X>x)+P(X<x)=1$
So if you calculate $P(X>x)$ for a cdf then
$P(X<x)=1-P(X>x)$?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly if you ever think that evaluating $\mathsf P(X>x)$ seems easier than $\mathsf P(X\leqslant x)$, you may then find the CDF via: $$\mathsf P(X\leqslant x) = 1-\mathsf P(X>x)$$

And of course, if instead you can fnd the *Cummulative Distribution Function* easier, you can find the *Survival Function* via $$\mathsf P(X\gt x) = 1-\mathsf P(X\leqslant x)$$

Use whichever works best for the problem at hand.

$~$

---

PS: Notice that the equality is actually $\mathsf P(X{<}x)+\mathsf P(X{=}x)+\mathsf P(X{>}x)=1$.   The middle term is *zero* for continuous random variables, but *may* be non-zero for discrete random variables.   In either case, the CDF is defined using non-strict inequality, $\mathsf P(X\leqslant x)=\mathsf P(X<x)+\mathsf P(X=x)$

Answer (score 0):

Generally cdf  P(X < x) is calculated first  using pdf f(x)

P(X > x) can be calculated by help of cdf

hence
P(X > x) = 1 - P( X< x)